# Optical Drive Not Writing Data To Disc

Tags: windows, optical-drive

I have a Lenovo Z580 Laptop running Windows 7 Ultimate SP-1. I had an issue with my optical drive; it read CD/DVD perfectly but couldn't write. Out of 5 attempts, it would fail 2-3 times.

I complained and got it replaced from Lenovo. Again, I faced the same issue with the new optical drive. It read CD/DVD but couldn't write. So, I complained once again and again got it replaced with a SONY Optiarc Optical Drive. But. still I am facing the same issue.

I know something was wrong with my very first optical drive. But, what is wrong with these new ones?

- I uninstalled the CD/DVD drive from the device manager until Windows re-installed it itself.
- I ran Microsoft fix-it troubleshooter and it claimed to fix some drive filter-issue. But, the problem still persists.

What should I do? Is clean re-installation of Windows the only solution?

Comment: Are you using a new disc each time?  What burning software are you using or are you using the built in burning engine?  In device manager, double click on the CD/DVD part and see if there are any error codes on the driver.  Report back what you see.

Comment: Have you installed all Windows Updates? Are you using the most current manufacturer driver for the drive? Is the computer clean of viruses and malware? Have you ran hardware diagnostics? Are there any error messages in Event Viewer?

Comment: @Travis : I have tried with new discs. No error codes on drive.

Comment: @CharlieRB : Yes, I have installed windows updates. My computer is clean of viruses and malware. I had run Microsoft fix-it troubleshooter for CD/DVD drive.

Comment: Try booting a Linux live system (USB or CD/DVD, doesn't matter) and see if you can reproduce the problem there. Ubuntu or Fedora should work. That will rule out the possibility that you've been having Lenovo ship you CD/DVD drives *for a software problem* (Windows).

Comment: What software are you using to write? and at what speed? try at a slower speed.

Comment: @cjb110 : I have used CyberLink Power2Go v5, Nero, ImgBurn. Speeds have been like 8x.

Comment: @allquixotic : I think I should give it a try.

Comment: Try burning at 1x, if that works consistently then try changing the media, maybe you've got a bad batch.